# Symfony 6 Remember Me Token is not serialized

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, security

Firstly, I'm implementing custom authenticator and this is my configuration:

```yaml
# security.yaml
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: user_provider
      custom_authenticator: Auth\Infrastructure\Middleware\LoginAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: /auth/logout
        target: /auth/login
      remember_me:
        secret: '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 604800
```

My custom authenticator have is this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;

final class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
// ...
    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->get("email");
        $password = $request->get("password");

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new CustomCredentials(function ($credentials, User $user) {
                return true;
            }, $password
            ),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge(
                    'authenticate',
                    $request->get("_csrf_token")
                ),
                new RememberMeBadge(),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

My **User** entity implements

```php
final class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
```

If I check 'Remember Me' in form, this add a cookie with name "REMEMBERME" but the value of this cookie is (example): `Auth.Domain.Model.User.User%3AbWFpbEBtYWlsLmNvbQ~~%3A1676621213%3AlZRwAuW6sgZ54opmAK3jTvohrrOUIWRAX6dDNiWtox0~tw46ZbKC_zkuDzY0qEC2gxooxSbzrlDNp-FZ624Nw4U~` the problem is it's including the namespace of my **User** entity, and it shouldn't, or should it? I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/RememberMeDetails.php#L90) for `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\RememberMeDetails::toString()`, your cookie is normal:

```php
    public function toString(): string
    {
        // $userIdentifier is encoded because it might contain COOKIE_DELIMITER, we assume other values don't
        return implode(self::COOKIE_DELIMITER, [strtr($this->userFqcn, '\\', '.'), strtr(base64_encode($this->userIdentifier), '+/=', '-_~'), $this->expires, $this->value]);
    }
```

The string is composed of the user class FQCN with `\` replaced with `.`, followed by other parts and separated by a `:` which is encoded as `%3A`.
In your case:

- userFqcn: `Auth.Domain.Model.User.User`
- userIdentifier: `bWFpbEBtYWlsLmNvbQ~~`
- expires: `1676621213`
- value: `lZRwAuW6sgZ54opmAK3jTvohrrOUIWRAX6dDNiWtox0~tw46ZbKC_zkuDzY0qEC2gxooxSbzrlDNp-FZ624Nw4U~`

Comment: value i pasted is correct? It should include the namespace? I expected to don't see/read the namespace just 'random' characters which are serialized, have to implement a custom token provider? Thanks for source! :)

Comment: @S.Wasta an FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) contains the namespace too, so yes the value looks correct to me :) I have no idea about how you could change the cookie value.